# wso2 token request failing because of @carbon.super

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 API manager v1.10.0 (which uses Carbon 4.4.3) and am sending a POST to get an auth token. The POST is:

POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.182.129:8280
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=password&username=test%40eztouch.net&password=00t3%24t&client_id=UJg5964pWSZPus_03WdVTJ83raQa&client_secret=2jcf3Nn17VNOHv2nZf01adf_5SEa

The return is:

{"error_description":"Authentication failed for test@eztouch.net@carbon.super","error":"invalid_grant"}

I have confirmed the username, password, client_id, and client_secret are all correct.

My repository/conf/carbon.xml has line:
true

I expected that with EnableEmailUserName set to true that it would not be appending the @carbon.super but it appears to be doing so. This same configuration works properly in my API manager v1.4 system.

Does anyone know why it is appending @carbon.super? Or do I have some other problem?

Thanks,

Todd

Comment: My carbon.xml file has: <EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether the Oauth2 application you are using has password grant type? (login to management console). I was able to generate the tokens without any issue by enabling the email username

following are my curl request and response

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=chamila@wso2.com&password=admin@123" -H "Authorization: Basic Um5TZkhFU29nMEhhUHVzeVN1dTRqcG15dmZZYTpUWGxDbkM2ckQ5Mm9CX295cDFkbDhvdFhyazRh" https://172.17.0.1:8243/token
```

Response

```
{"scope":"default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"a8f48cd35ad009fcbe5923dc44d5c9fe","access_token":"e557307498265260f13637138fdfb726"}
```